# How to add a sprite.position value inside a variable XCODE - SPRITEKIT

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to add a sprite.position value inside  a variable, a float, a int etc. 
Kind of like:
//HEADER FILE:
    `int *spritePositionX;` 
    `int *spritePositionY;`

//IMPLEMENTATION FILE

```
spritePosition = sprite.position.x;
spritePosition = sprite.position.y;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

header:

```
CGPoint spritePosition;
```

implementation:

```
spritePosition = sprite.position;
// spritePosition = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x, sprite.position.y);
```

Comment: Thank you man. The spritePosition = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x, sprite.position.y); worked perfectly

Comment: @Soundbust glad to hear that was what you were looking for! There is also `CGPointZero`, which always returns `CGPointMake(0,0);`. For debugging you can use `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(spritePosition);`